# Spotting the existence of asymptotes using calculus?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, graphing-functions

Are there any requirements that when they are fulfilled (as far as the derivatives of a function are concerned) then a function will always have an asymptote?(a straight line asymptote)(for example one could guess that such a requirement that would automatically mean that the function has an horizontal (for example) line asymptote would be that the derivative of the function as x approaches infinity approaches zero but that is not true as in the example of the function f(x)=lnx it proves that a function can have zero derivative as x approaches infinity while the function does not have horizontal asymptote) If in my question above there do exist such requirements how can they be proven?

Comment: There is a sense in which every function has an asymptote, e.g., as $x\to\infty$, the function $y=f(x)$ has $y=f(x)+e^{-x}$ as an asymptote. You really need to find an airtight definition of "asymptote" to have any hope of getting a useful answer to your question.

Comment: I suppose OP mean straigh-line asymptotes. Then for $y=f(x)$ to have slanted or horizontal asymptote one needs $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ to exist, where $\infty$ is $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. For $y=f(x)$ to have vertical asymptote one needs $\lim_{x\to a_1}f(x)=\infty$ where $a_1$ is $a+0$ or $a-0$ at some $a$, $\infty$ is $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: As for sufficient condition for slanted or horizontal asymptote: $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-kx-b)=0$ at some $k$ and $b$, where $\infty$ is $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. $k$ is the same value as $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$.

Comment: I think the derivative is irrelevant, Kani. $f(x)=x^{-1/2}\sin(x^2)$ has $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, so the $x$-axis is a horizontal asymptote, but the derivative is unbounded as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Any thoughts about the comments, Kani?

Comment: Earth to Kani – come in, please.

Comment: I think Gerry you are right that the derivatives are not always connected  with the existence of line assymptotes. So maybe we cannot find some conditions that contain the derivatives which must always be fulfilled in order for a line asymptote to exist. Thank you for your help!